# How to stick a iAddBanner above the tab bar and keep it there

Tags: iphone, position, storyboard, tabbar

I'm trying to use a iAddBanner, and place it right on top of my tabbar.
This is giving me some problems, especially in the tableviews....

Is there anyone who has successfully done this?

Cheers,
Tommy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem on my own.

I ended up adding the adbanner as a subview of my tabbarcontroller.

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [iAdBanner setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 381, 200, 32)];
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:iAdBanner];
    //The inset is for the current tableview to get all the content on top of the adbanner
    UIEdgeInsets inset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 50, 0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = inset;
    adVisible = true;
}
```